# Views query alter for specific node/content type

Tags: 7, views

My idea are instead of update the views
name to the custom code one by one. I like to apply to same content type, but
I don't know the syntax.

```
 function myModule_views_query_alter(&$view, &$query)

   if(($view->name == '?????????'){

}
```

I would get the node/content type "myArticle" for node table as following code

```
$content_type = $wrapper->type->value();
```

but how can I update `$view->name` to `$views->node->type` ? I try `print_r` the `$view` but not fully understand the syntax  to access the field. Not sure if I went in the wrong direction. Please advise.

Comment: Can you please elaborate upon the requirement. I am not able to get what exactly do you wish to achieve

Comment: 1. i created custom content type  for Group doc.  called dept_article
2.  then add node custom field department (term "department ID") to the dept_article.
3.  then create user role Dept mgr, staff,  mgt
4.  then add user custom field rom admin > people again called field department (term "department ID")

now i want to use hook views query alter. 
 if content type = dept_artile and $role = then
  $query=>add_where()....

i think alter the query ref to role is easier for beginner,  compare to create a more complex module.

Answer (score 0):

If You only want to display data for specific roles to specific persons then you can use Global php in views to filter your results, Just take "User: Roles (Roles)" in your field as excluded and use its token in Global PHP field.example

```
if([roles] == "admin"){print [your_field_token_name];}
elseif([roles] == "your_roles"){print [your_field_token_name];}
```

You have to download the module of [viewsphp](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_php) to use global php.

Comment: hello Ranjan, thanks for you reply, i never try token programming, need to study first, by the way, is there any way to do without additional Module, thanks, have a nice weekend and Max's Christmas..!

Comment: Hello, Using a tokens are not a bigger task, actually views already makes a tokens for their use also and the module "viewsphp" make you enable to write PHP in views and if you want to use hook_views_query_alter that's also easy

you can use details of add_where syntax here: https://api.drupal.org/api/views/plugins%21views_plugin_query_default.inc/function/views_plugin_query_default%3A%3Aadd_where/7.x-3.x may this helps you...add_where($group, $field, $value = NULL, $operator = NULL) and let me know if any other help, thanks and Marry christmas ...!